# Vacuum solutions to the EFEs

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology

I was wondering if there are any papers in which authors have compared cosmological observations to those phenomena predicted by vacuum solutions to the EFEs?

Obviously there is matter in the universe, but I had somebody tell me that vacuum models can sometimes serve as a good approximation since the universe is mostly empty space.

Is this true? Have there been any publications where researchers compared vacuum models to observation with some kind of benefit?

I'm quite uninformed on this topic, and don't quite understand the depth of the question I am asking.

Answer (score 3):

The basic problem with this is the so-called "cosmological principle". We expect the Universe to be 'homogeneous' (statistically the same no matter where you look, provided you zoom out far enough) and 'isotropic' (the same no matter how you rotate it). Failure of either condition would essentially mean that the Universe has a centre, which would be weird. Perhaps more compellingly, the models we get by making these assumptions work very well for the vast majority of the Universe's history.

So, one goes and plugs these two symmetries into the EFEs. They turn out to be sufficient to specify the FLRW class of solutions, which are not vacuum solutions. Turning this on its head: no vacuum solution can recover the expected symmetries.